# Compare stings with localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare - ß-Problem

Tags: swift, macos, compare

I try to compare strings in swift with localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare but I get some strange behavior:

```
let str1 = "Eßb"
let str2 = "Esb"
let result = str.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(str2)
print(result.rawValue)
```

The ß-char seems to be a problem.

```
"ß" > "s"      bacause: "ss" > "s"
"Eß" > "Es"    bacause: "Ess" > "Es"
"Eßb" < "Esb"  bacause: WHY?
```

I understand the first two results, but not the third.
For this reason, my binary insert function is not working properly.
Can someone help?